# Raspberry pi 4 4gb can run ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: raspberry-pi4

Im so sorry i have not perfect english, but.

I would like to know if ubuntu 18.04 server is running correctly in raspberry pi 4 4GB ?
On google i look a specialy website and the person said that ubuntu can run with just 1gb, it's true ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Yes, you can. There are many sites that discuss doing so.

Comment: Ok thanks, just one last question, how much ram is left when ubuntu is running approximately 50% ?